# Error en php, exporta tags html junto al resultado

Tags: php, html

Buenas compañeros
Tengo un problema al exportar datos en php desde una consulta en mysqli. El problema se da que al abrir el archivo tengo todo el encabezado html y luego los datos que solicite. 
Nose si es un problema de sintaxis mio o si me falta algo para limpiar el archivo.
Aqui va el codigo que utilizo.

```
<?php 
require('conexion.php');

$fcdesde=$_POST['fechaDesde'];
$fchasta=$_POST['fechaHasta'];

$registros=mysqli_query($conexion,"select p.idPedido, p.fecha, f.nombre,i.descripcion,p.motivo, p.cantidad
                                     from pedidos as p
                                    inner join farmacias as f on f.idFarmacia = p.idFarmacia
                                    inner join tiposinsumos as i on i.idtipoInsumo = p.idtipoInsumo
                                    where p.fecha between '$fcdesde' and '$fchasta'
                                    and p.borrado = 1 and p.enviado = 0
                                    order by p.fecha ASC")
                                    or die ("Problemas en el select:-> ").mysqli_error($conexion);

$numeroFilas = mysqli_num_rows($registros);

if ($numeroFilas > 0)
{
    $delimitador = ";";
    $nombreArchivo = "Pedidos ".date('d-m-Y').".csv";
    //creo los headers para la descarga
    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $nombreArchivo . '";');
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

    $f = fopen('php://memory','w');
    $cabecera=array('Pedido Nro','Fecha','Farmacia','Insumo','Motivo','Cantidad');
    //agrego las cabecera
    fputcsv($f,$cabecera,$delimitador);
    //agrego las lineas
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($registros))
    {
        $linea=array($row['idPedido'],$row['fecha'],$row['nombre'],$row['descripcion'],$row['motivo'],$row['cantidad']);
        fputcsv($f,$linea,$delimitador);
    }
    fseek($f,0);
    fpassthru($f);
    fclose($f);
    mysqli_close($conexion);        
}else if ($numeroFilas == 0) {
     echo "<script>alert('Su tabla no pudo ser exportado exitosamente, Verifique que ingreso los datos');location.href ='javascript:history.back()';</script>";
}   

exit; ?>
```

Y el resultado que obtengo es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me podrian dar una mano.
Gracias!

Comment: ¿Has visto si en otros ficheros estás renderizando el layout antes de tiempo? Empezaría por `conexion.php` e iría tirando del hilo de los requires o include que tuviesen a su vez. También miraría si este fichero que has pegado está incluido en otro y ese otro renderiza el layout.

Comment: Si el código va a ser ejecutado como un script (no navegador), debes eliminar todo el HTML que haya, ya que el interprete lo devolverá tal cual a la salida.

Comment: ok @ordago reviso eso. Gracias!

Comment: @aeportugal trate de hacerlo por jquery, pero no lo logre todavia, jeje. Gracias